# Which Value Pass to Param Select all Records in Mongo DB Collections using Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Which value pass to param select all  records in mongo db collections using meteor.

For Example :

```
var filterResult = auth_user.find({staff:0,issuper:0}).fetch();
```

The above one to pass either 0 or 1 this time not a problem.But some times pass only staff value and issuper is to select all records and vice versa.If not given two values select all records in a collection.

I need the above one in a single query? is it possible or suggest me what to do for this?

Comment: I don't think your question is understandable. You can use variables or if else blocks to search for different searches if that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know what you're asking but in general you can get everything in the collection without any query at all:

```
var filterResult = auth_user.find({}).fetch();
```